# Como reduzir a captura de grupos em uma expressão regular?

Tags: regex

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

```
/((segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta|sábado|domingo)+(((-feira)?)+(.)+\(([0-9].*)\))?)/im
```

Que me traz:

> Espetáculo Trueque se apresenta neste sábado no teatro da CDL

```
RESULTADO: sábado
```

> Bandas de rock se apresentam nesta sexta (5) no espaço Marcus Moraes

```
RESULTADO: sexta (5), sexta, 5, etc.
```

> Loja de decoração inaugura novo espaço nesta terça-feira (15)

```
RESULTADO: terça-feira (15), terça, -feira (15), 15 etc.
```

Como faço torna esta expressão menos 'gulosa'?

Comment: Testando aqui me pareceu normal: http://www.regexr.com/
 Como está executando ela?

Comment: Como você faz pra ler os resultados?

Comment: Estou executando como preg_match. Só achei que talvez pudesse torna-lá mais light. Visto que estou usando muitos Grupo '()'. Já li algo a respeito que grupo é inversamente proporcional a desempenho.

Comment: Quando você diz "menos 'gulosa'" você quer dizer no sentido figurativo ou literal? Pois existe um conceito em regex chamado ***greedy*** (em português, gulosa [nesse contexto; lit. gananciosa]), cujo uso ou não afetaria os seus resultados (ex.: gulosa: "terça-feira (15)", preguiçosa / *lazy*: "terça"). Pelo que entendi do seu comentário anterior, não é a isso que se refere, por isso sugiro alterar o título da pergunta com uma expressão alternativa ("mais light", ou "mais concisa" parece uma boa) pra não causar ambiguidade.

Comment: Gostaria de sugerir a você que mude sua pergunta, acrescentando um detalhe importante: qual a resposta que você *espera* conseguir da Regex, pra todos os casos possíveis? Com exemplos ou não, mas isso é uma coisa que não está tão clara na sua pergunta. Com a frase "Bandas de rock se apresentam nesta sexta (5) no espaço Marcus Moraes" deseja-se APENAS "sexta (5)" como resultado?

Comment: Ele mostrou todas as combinações e resultados - está na questão

Comment: @mgibsonbr sei que faz tempo, mas nunca tinha notado esta pergunta, talvez pelo titulo mesmo. Ajustei o titulo, quem usa regex sabe o que é grupo, então *"reduzir a captura de grupos"* me parece apropriado para quem vier por buscadores, mas se tiver outra ideia irá ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 4):

Acredito que essa seja a melhor expressão (e mais simplificada também) para o seu caso. Lembre-se que não apenas uma expressão regular tem que ser eficiente, mas fácil de entender.

```
/(((segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)(-feira)?)|sábado|domingo)(\s*\(\d+\))?/g
```

Funciona com:

```
segunda
terça
quarta
quinta
sexta
sábado
domingo
segunda-feira
terça-feira
quarta-feira
quinta-feira
sexta-feira
segunda (25)
terça (26)
quarta (27)
quinta (28)
sexta (29)
sábado (30)
domingo (31)
segunda-feira (1)
terça-feira (2)
quarta-feira (3)
quinta-feira (4)
sexta-feira (5)
```

Não funciona com:

```
sábado-feira
domingo-feira
sábado-feita (6)
domingo-feira (7)
-feira
-feira (8)
```

Link no regexr: http://regexr.com/39e5i

Answer (score 3):

[Nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25773/reduzir-express%c3%a3o-gulosa#comment47837_25773) você disse que está usando `preg_match`. E se olharmos a [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), é dito que nos resultados dos *matches* também são retornados os grupos de captura.

No caso, [os grupos de captura são criados pelos parênteses](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), e você usa muitos deles na sua regex. Existe um grupo só para o dia da semana sem o sufixo "-feira", outro só para o próprio sufixo "-feira", outro para os números entre parênteses, outro em volta da expressão inteira, etc.

Se você não quer tantos grupos assim e só precisa do *match* inteiro, basta transformar os parênteses em [grupos de não-captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html#noncap), iniciando-os com `(?:`. O parênteses em volta da expressão inteira também não é necessário, já que o trecho correspondente a toda a regex sempre é retornado. Então ficaria assim:

```
/(?:(?:segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)(?:-feira)?|sábado|domingo)(?:\s+\([0-9]+\))?/i
```

Em código PHP ficaria algo do tipo:

```php
$str = 'Espetáculo Trueque se apresenta neste sábado no teatro da CDL'.
       'Bandas de rock se apresentam nesta sexta (5) no espaço Marcus Moraes'.
       'Loja de decoração inaugura novo espaço nesta terça-feira (15)';

preg_match_all('/(?:(?:segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)(?:-feira)?|sábado|domingo)(?:\s+\([0-9]+\))?/i', $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $m) {
    echo $m.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Saída:

```
sábado
sexta (5)
terça-feira (15)
```

Agora todos os parênteses começam com `(?:`, o que os torna grupos de não-captura. Por isso os respectivos trechos não fazem mais parte do *match*, somente o trecho correspondente à regex inteira.

Outras melhorias:

- `(?:(?:segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)(?:-feira)?|sábado|domingo)`: a alternância diz que somente de segunda a sexta pode ter um "-feira" depois (o `?` indica que o trecho "-feira" é [opcional](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)). Já sábado e domingo não podem ter o sufixo "-feira".
- `\s+`: o atalho `\s` corresponde a espaços e quebras de linha, entre outros caracteres ([a lista exata varia conforme a linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/405703/112052)) e o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências". Ou seja, pode ter um ou mais espaços
- `[0-9]+`: um ou mais dígitos de 0 a 9. Aqui você até poderia usar algo como `(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])` para que aceite apenas valores entre `1` e `31` (que são os valores válidos para o dia do mês - sendo que os dias menores que 10 podem ter um zero à esquerda, ou seja, aceita tanto `1` quanto `01`, [veja](https://regex101.com/r/IfTQ3T/1/)), fica a seu critério.
- `(?:\s+\([0-9]+\))?`: todo o trecho "espaço + números entre parênteses" possui um `?` logo depois, o que torna este trecho opcional

Na sua regex você estava usando as [*flags*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) `i` e `m` (no final, o trecho `/im`). A *flag*
 `i` torna a regex *case insensitive*, então se a string tiver "Segunda-Feira" ou "DOMINGO", ela também encontra. Já a *flag* `m` muda o comportamento dos [marcadores](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` e `$` (normalmente correspondem ao início e fim da string, mas com a *flag* `m` eles mudam o significado para início e fim de uma linha). Como você não usa esses marcadores, removi a *flag* `m` da regex.

---

No exemplo acima eu usei [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php), que traz todas as ocorrências da string, mas se quiser buscar por somente uma ocorrência, use `preg_match`:

```php
preg_match('/(?:(?:segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta)(?:-feira)?|sábado|domingo)(?:\s+\([0-9]+\))?/i', $str, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $m) {
    echo $m;
}
```

Comment: Isto está merecendo uma recompensa, e não pela resposta toda, mas principalmente porque citou o `?:` (não-captura) +1 (em breve a recompensa, 7 dias)

Answer (score 0):

Simplifiquei um pouco sua expressão para pegar apenas os grupos internos. Não sei se o objetivo é pegar uma empressão por frase, mas o que obtive foi o seguinte:

```
(segunda|terça|quarta|quinta|sexta|sábado|domingo)+((-feira)?(.)+\(([0-9]{1,2})\))?
```

Comment: Repare que essa expressão produz resultados diferentes da que o Iago colocou na pergunta, talvez mais certa, por falta de um `.`. Teste com `sexta (5sddf)` que verá.

Comment: É mesmo. Já ajustei.