# Expressão regular em python não pega a string completa

Tags: python, regex

Estou utilizando este código em python, esperando como retorno `[1,5L]` mas o que eu recebo é `[,5]`, onde eu estou errando?

```
string = "0000000212 - COCA-COLA PET 1,5L C6"
print(re.findall(r'\d+(\,\d+)?\s?[L|ML]{1}', string))
```

Comment: O que significa a sua expressão? Talvez ela explica o seu erro.

Answer (score 2):

Parênteses formam um grupo de captura, e a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) diz que, quando a regex tem algum grupo, `findall` retorna apenas o conteúdo dos grupos.

No seu caso você colocou apenas a vírgula seguida de dígitos entre parênteses, por isso  o retorno só tem o trecho correspondente.

Para retornar tudo, basta trocar os parênteses por um [grupo de não-captura](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/427265/112052), colocando `?:` depois do `(`.

Outro detalhe é que a vírgula não precisa ser escapada com `\`.

E `[L|ML]` na verdade significa a letra "L", ou o caractere `|`, ou a letra "M", ou a letra "L" (apenas uma delas). Se a ideia é pegar "L" ou "ML", pode trocar para `M?L` - a interrogação indica que o `M` é opcional (também poderia ser `(?:ML|L)`, mas nesse caso eu acho mais simples `M?L`).

E `{1}` significa "uma ocorrência", mas é redundante e desnecessário: `(qualquer coisa){1}` é o mesmo que `(qualquer coisa)`.

Ou seja, ficaria assim:

```py
print(re.findall(r'\d+(?:,\d+)?\s?M?L', string))
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Comment: @ÂngeloGabriel Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.